# Probability of seating on a toboggan

Tags: probability

If I have a toboggan, and there are 5 boys, and 2 girls, what is the probability that 4 or more boys are sitting next to each other? What is the answer and how could I solve more like it?

Comment: How many can fit on this toboggan?

Comment: You can consider two cases: All four at the front are boys, or not. In the second case you can look for the amount of arrangements of gbbbb, b, g. Note that this only works because 5<4*2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all 7 children are on the toboggan

the total number of seating arrangements are $\binom 72=21$

Five boys a in a row can be placed among the girls in  $\binom 31=3 $ ways

A group of four boys can also be placed among the girls in 3 ways , in each case leaving 2 places to put the remaining boy

So $$P = \frac{3+6}{21} =\frac 37 $$

Comment: Why is the 5 boys in a row 3 choose 1, while the 4 boys in a row is 7 choose 2?

Comment: There are three ways to position five boys in a row among the 2 girls , in front, in the middle and at the end. The $\binom 72$ is the TOTAL arrangements without any restrictions, it is the number of ways of choosing positions for the 2 girls among the 7 children.

Comment: What restrictions are there? And what about the 3 choose 1?